# Variable in value in key-value pairs in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, sympy

Let's say we have `dictionary = ['a':x*2,'b':x*3]`, and we set `x` to 2. When I print out the dictionary after this assignment, I get the one shown above, and not `['a':4,'b':6]`. Why is that? I am currently trying to come up with a solution to Project Euler exercise 69 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=69) for which I have made the following:

```
import math

from sympy import Symbol

magic_book={1:1,2:1}

maximum=0

for n in range(3,10**6+1):

    print(magic_book)
    print(n)
    if n in magic_book:
        if (n/magic_book[n])>maximum:
            maximum=n/magic_book[n]
        continue
        
    Phi=0
    x = Symbol('x')
    
    for m in range(1,n):
        if math.gcd(n,m)==1:
            magic_book[n*m]=x*magic_book[m]
            Phi+=1
    x=Phi
    if n/Phi>maximum:
        maximum=n/Phi
    
print(maximum)
```

When I set `x` equal `Phi`, `magic_book` does not update - why is this?

Comment: It looks like you've asked this question a different way here, so this is now a duplicate: [Assigning value to \`x\` doesn't calculate sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038960/assigning-value-to-x-doesnt-calculate-sum)

Answer (score 1):

When you edit an object in Python, it does not go back and change what you previously stated using it. See for example:

```py
x = 1
double_x = 2*x
x = 10
```

Your question is basically asking why `double_x` is not 20.

In order to substitute symbolic values with other values (like numeric values), `.subs()` is usually the best option if you are dealing with SymPy objects. However, a dictionary is not a SymPy object and it does not have a `.subs()` method. You must then loop through the dictionary and substitute its values like so:

```py
for k, v in magic_book.items():
    maximum[k] = v.subs(x, Phi)  # assuming v is a SymPy object
```