# Assigning value to `x` doesn't calculate sum

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following problem:

```
x=Symbol('x') 
book={1:2*x,2:3*x}
x=2
print(book) >>> {1:2*x,2:3*x}
```

I had hoped it would print `{1:4,2:6}`

But if I set `book={1:2*x,2:3*x}`
just before the print statement, I get the wanted result.

The frustrating thing is, if I instead write `book=book`, which should be the same (right?), just before the print statement, I get `{1:2*x,2:3*x}` - why is that?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is Python 3

Comment: The assignment `x = 2` has no effect whatsoever on the `Symbol` object that `x` previously pointed at; it just makes `x` point at the object for the number `2` instead. The `book` dictionary still points at the unchanged `Symbol` object.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with two different values of `x` because you're talking about setting `x` to something other than `Symbol('x')` in one case but not the other.  In one case:

```
x=Symbol('x') 
book={1:2*x,2:3*x}
x=2
print(book)
```

Result:

```
{1: 2*x, 2: 3*x}
```

`x` was `Symbol('x')` when you created `book`.  It doesn't matter that you later set `x` to `2`.

In your other case, if I understand you right:

```
x=Symbol('x')
x=2
book={1:2*x,2:3*x}
print(book) >>> {1:2*x,2:3*x}
```

Result:

```
{1: 4, 2: 6}
```

`x` is now `2` when you build `book`, so your result now has nothing to do with `sympy`.  It's just regular Python arithmetic, and so you get computed values in your dict.

If what you want is `{1: 4, 2: 6}`, why are you using `sympy` at all?

To answer your final question, you're asking why adding the line `book = book` doesn't change the result.  Why would it?  That line doesn't do anything. `book` is the same value after that line is run that it was before.